# 5000W heater temperature

Tags: heater, temperature

Garage Heater

My 5000 W heater is wired to a double breaker (220V) 10 GA.black & white wires + grd.) feeding the heater (Dimplex). The heater element will generate only 140 degrees on the heater element surface tested by thermocouple meter lead.

Canadian Tech service says to use a SINGLE wire 220V feed?? The diagram clearly shows L1 & L2 along with ground.

1) is my wiring correct?
2) should I expect more heat from this 5000 W - 220V

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

The wiring should be:

Black: one side of the double breaker to heater terminal A

White: Other side of the double breaker to heater terminal B (this wire should be tagged black or red. Use a marker or some tape.

Single-wire 220v means there is no 120v in the circuit, like a stove.

There is no fixed temperature for a given power consumption. How hot does the manual say it should get?

Comment: Thanks Paul, That is how I have it wired and marked for safety. Unfortunately, neither the Mfg. or the manual state expected temperature??

Comment: The tech (in French/broken english) kept saying 220V on a single wire. However, the manual clearly shows L1 & L2??

Comment: Confirm that there are only two power connectors on the heater. And if you have a clamp-on ammeter confirm that it is pulling about 20 amps.

Comment: Only 2 contact period - don't have a clamp on meter unfortunately! This thing "looks" like an electric stove heating element with a fan and thermostat -very simple - can't believe the element only heats to 140 deg.????

Comment: 140 degrees is quite possible for a 5000 watt heater. but it will heat a *lot* of, for example, water to that temperature. Power and temperature are only loosely related.